# Fast solution to fill create and fill db table with data from csv file

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, fill

Like in title.. I want to create table in my db and then fill it with records from my csv(tab is ";") file. There records (and whole table) won't be updating or changing by anyone. I just have to create db(only Postgres) with these records. I want later take randomly from this table some records. Any tips? Or maybe taking random records directly from csv file instad from db is better solution? Plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a command line tool that reads your cvs file and use ActiveModel to talk to the database. In this case you create your Model and Database as you would do in any other rails Application.

To read your cvs file you culd do this:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach(fileName, :headers => true, encoding: "UTF-8") do |row|
  row['myfiled'].to_s
end
```

You need the csv gem and you have to replace myfield with the name of the column you want to use. If you have the data in ruby you create your models as if you would to in rails. Put the definitions in the same file or use require to reference your models.

Alternatively you could just read the cvs file and randomly decide if you want to use the data. In this case you do not need to put it in the database.

Comment: thanks! But can You suggest, which way is faster? My csv file have some around 100 000 lines (records) so I think that working on db will be faster than opening big file every time, am I right?

Comment: It depends on how many times you want to get random lines from it. If you want to do it only once the cvs only solution is faster (you do not need the overhead of persisting the data). 
But if you want do run it multiple times put it in the database. In this case you only parse the cvs once and all the reads go to the database.

Comment: how add a file path if my csv file is in assets/images/file.csv?